# How to improve this Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I wrote a powershell script that merges go pro video files if they have multiple files. It works when the videos are at the root drive i.e. C:, but otherwise not. The mergevideos.txt file is not created if I run the script from a different directory. Or the txt is created but it's empty. Not sure what's going on when run from a different directory.

So is there a way to fix these issues and refactor this code to make it better? Ideally I want the script to automatically look at the directory it's in or allows me to specify the directory it should work in so I can just call it from the same location but the videos can be anywhere.

```
$path = "C:/NewVideos/"
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem -Path $path *.mp4
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $curpath = $oldvid.DirectoryName

    $name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($oldvid)
    $ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($oldvid)
    if ($name.StartsWith("GX01") -and !($name.EndsWith("_merged")))
    {
        $newvid = $curpath + $name + "_merged" + $ext
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($newvid))
        {
            Write-Output "$name | ALREADY MERGED"
            continue
        }

        $count = 1

        for ($num = 2; $num -lt 10; $num++)
        {
            $nextpart = $name.Replace("GX01", "GX0" + $num)
            if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($curpath + "/" + $nextpart + $ext))
            {
                $count = $num
            }
        }

        if ($count -eq 1)
        {
            Write-Output "$name | SINGLE VIDEO"
            continue
        }

        $mergefile = $curpath + "mergevideos.txt"
        if (!(Test-Path $mergefile))
        {
            New-Item -path $curpath -name mergevideos.txt -type "file"
        }

        Clear-Content $mergefile

        for ($num = 1; $num -le $count; $num++)
        {
            $nextpart = $name.Replace("GX01", "GX0" + $num)
            $videofilename = "file '" + $nextpart + $ext + "'"
            Add-Content $mergefile $videofilename
        }

         Write-Output "$name | MERGING  $count VIDEOS"
         ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $mergefile -c copy $newvid
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s a fair bit of code to pick through so it’s hard to see where the issue might be - can you reduce it to an MRE? In any case, shouldn’t  ```$mergefile = $curpath + "mergevideos.txt"``` be ```$mergefile = $curpath + "/mergevideos.txt"```?

Comment: Try: [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path)`-LiteralPath $mergefile -PathType Leaf`

Comment: Yes that was an issue, I use Join-Path now.